# Ajax using information from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble using the information I get from my PHP file after an AJAX call.
I currently have the following AJAX code that triggers after clicking a button:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "nano.php",
                  data: { action: "authenticate" }
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                  alert( "Done: " + msg );
                });    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Than, in the nano.php file I do some authentication and information fetching. In the end of my PHP code I do the following:

```
  print_r($member_info);
  print_r($activity_info);
```

This information (two arrays with a lot of information) appear in the alert box that is called in the Ajax done function, which means that this information is available in the client side.

I want to be able to treat the arrays and show the information on the page. Is print_r the right way to send the information? How can I treat and show the information in the arrays in my page after this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To send an array from your PHP file back to Javascript through AJAX use:

`echo json_encode($array);`

Applies to strings too.

And change the expected response type to `json` in your jQuery.ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "nano.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { action: "authenticate" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Done: ");
   console.log(msg); // <- javascript array or object
 });
```

(or send a `application/json` content-type header from PHP)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is use a empty mark up in your html like `<div id="response"></div>`

In your php:

```
print_r(json_encode($member_info));
print_r (json_encode($activity_info));
```

And in your ajax call use this div to hold ajax reponse like this:

```
 $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "nano.php",
                  data: { action: "authenticate" }
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                  $("#response").html(msg);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a message in JSON, it's easier to manage it later in jQuery.

PHP:

```
$data = array( 'some_var' => 'some_value' );
echo json_encode( $data );
exit;
```

And then in jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "nano.php",
              data: { action: "authenticate" }
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                var data_object = JSON.parse(msg); // Create a Javascript object/array from the JSON
                // Here you can use the data inside the array/object
                alert( data_object.some_var );
            });    
    });
});
</script>
```